# Windows failover cluster from another domain

Tags: windows, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2016

So I am having an issue creating a failover cluster for 2 HyperV nodes. The 2 nodes have been joined to a domin of their own called hvtest.local. The PC I am tring to create the cluster from is on a different domain.

I am able to access the nodes via bothe HyperV manager and server manager, but when trying to validate or create a cluster I get the message: "The Node cannot be contacted. Ensure that the node is powered on and is connected to the network."

If I try to validate from the domain controller that the nodes are joined to, it works fine.

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a trust between the domains?

Comment: @longneck is that the only solution? I would like to keep the domains isolated as the reason I am looking into HyperV is so we can use it in our datacentre so it will eventually be on a seperate network where we VPN in to manage it (still from our PC's on the company domain).